# Could this be a defective new tire, only 5 days old?

Tags: tires, damage, sidewall-damage

Inside of front, passenger tire sustained damage to the side wall causing it to go flat. Wife swears she didn't hit anything other than running over the remnants of a tire from a truck on the highway.

Could this have caused the damage?

Could it be a defective tire? I've never had a tire this new go flat and not know how it happened.

[image]

Comment: They don't call them *road alligators* for nothing. They can and will destroy a good tire.

Answer (score 3):

Yes its possible that the truck tyre your wife ran over did the damage.. Tyres, especially truck tyres have larger and thicker wire beads and belts.. Assuming this truck tyre was shredded its likely had its beads or belts exposed which can be extremely sharp. As the tyre parts have been run over they can twist and fold up quite easily under the weight of another vehicle which is likely how your sidewall has been punctured. 
Unfortunately its not possible to safely repair sidewall damage as the structure of the tyre has been compromised.

Comment: Copy that. I appreciate the response